# Using QBWeb Connector to Sync Customers

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am facing this issue, when i am trying to create new customer in Quick Books.

I was having actual name of Customer at my php side was "***IbáñezOmar***" and when it converts to UTF-8 encoding, it becomes "***IbÃ¡Ã±ezOmar***".
But when this customer created in Quick Books the name totally changes to "***Ib????ezOmar***"

Please can anyone help how can i fix this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?qbxml version="11.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
    <CustomerAddRq>
      <CustomerAdd>
        <Name >IbÃ¡Ã±ezOmar</Name>
        <IsActive >1</IsActive>
        <CompanyName >IbÃ¡Ã±ezOmar</CompanyName>
        <Salutation ></Salutation>
        <FirstName >Omar</FirstName>
        <LastName >IbÃ¡Ã±ez</LastName>
        <Contact >Omar IbÃ¡Ã±ez</Contact>
      </CustomerAdd>
    </CustomerAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: Post the complete request including the xml headers.

Comment: Please have a look, i have updated the request XML